# Dynamic allocation of a struct in C

Tags: c, realloc

I have a char* within a "news" struct like this:

```
typedef struct news{
        char *name;
}news;
```

I read from a file some text (in example I have ever the same line:hello). For the main and my function i wrote this code:

```
int insert(news **note, char *text,int i);

int main(){
   news *note;
   int i=0,j;
   note = malloc(sizeof(news));

   for (j=0;j<5;j++){
          i=insert(&not,"hello",i);
          printf("%s\n",note[i-1].name);
   }
   system("pause");
}

int insert(news **note, char *text,int i){
    (*note)[i].name = malloc(strlen(text)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy((*note)[i].name,text);
    note = realloc((*note),++i*sizeof(news));
    return i;
}
```

Why do I get a segmentation fault for `j>2`? What is wrong?

Comment: At leat one problem: you need to allocate a size of `(strlen(text)*sizeof(char) + 1` for the string to take into account the zero terminator.

Comment: FWIW, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`.

Comment: I think `not = realloc(...)` should be `*note = realloc(...);`

Comment: I think the `&not` should be `&note` in the `for loop`

Comment: While we're at it, you should never assign the return value of `realloc()` to the original pointer, because that way you cannot recover if `realloc()` fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with your allocation.

Instead of

```
not = realloc((*note),++i*sizeof(news));
```

use

```
*note = realloc((*note),(++i + 1) * sizeof(news));
```

is this working yet?

---

**Edit**:

Change also what *@Michael Walz* said in comment

Result of that is :

```
int insert(news **note, char *text,int i);

int main(){
   news *note = NULL;
   int i = 0;
   int j = 0;

   if ((note = malloc(sizeof(news))) == NULL) {
     return (-1);
   }

   for (j = 0; j < 5; ++j){
       i = insert(&note, "hello", i);

       printf("%s\n", note[i - 1].name);
   }

   system("pause");
}

int insert(news **note, char *text, int i) {
    (*note)[i].name = strdup(text);

    *note = realloc((*note), (++i + 1) * sizeof(news));

    return i;
}
```

Comment: You did all changement? What is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is here:

```
note = realloc((*note),++i*sizeof(news));
```

you are reallocating a static pointer because `note` is a `news**`

so use

```
*note = realloc((*note),(++i + 1)*sizeof(news));
```

thanks to RaNdoM_PoWneD

Comment: we are all giving the same answer ahaha :)

Comment: He just forget to use *note instead of note. If he does what you suggest, the realloc will being lost in memory. Cause note is a local variable

Comment: I'm trying the program and the error persists. There is an another issue.

Comment: allocate `code`++i * sizeof(news)`code` is equals to allocate 1*sizeof(news) because i is equals to 0 first time in loop (i equals 1 after ++i). He need to allocate `code`(++i + 1) * sizeof(news)`code`

Answer (score 1):

RaNdoM_PoWneD has provided a technically correct answer.

But your codes are not good. which is why you got into this trouble.

1. Why are you passing pointers-to-pointers?
2. What is the purpose of `j` in your main for-loop?
3. If you are intending to do things like `printf`, You need to make
   room for a `/0` when you `malloc` the `.name` member. Better still, since you are dynamically allocating it; add another member for the size of `.name` to the `news` struct.
4. Take the advice of DevSolar in the comments to the OP.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct news
{
    size_t size;
    char *name;
}
news;


news* insert(news *note, char *text, int i)
{
    //NB: if note is NULL realloc acts like malloc
    news* new_note=(news*)realloc(note, (i+1)*sizeof(news));
    if (new_note)
    {
        size_t size=strlen(text)*sizeof(char);
        new_note[i].size=size;
        new_note[i].name = malloc(size +1); //make room for /0
        strcpy(new_note[i].name,text); //copies trailing /0 as well
    }
    return (new_note);
}

int main()
{
    news *note=NULL;
    int j,k;

    for (j=0;j<5;j++)
    {
        news* new_note=insert(note,"hello",j);
        if (new_note)
        {
            note=new_note;
            printf("%s\n",note[j].name);
        }
        else //bork
            break;
   }


   //don't forget to free your allocations !
    for (k=0;k<j;k++)
        free(note[k].name);
    free(note);

   return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/DCmYpU

> Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place.
>   Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by
>   definition, not smart enough to debug it.
>   
>   
>   **Brian Kernighan**